# Distributed representations for words: How do I generate it?

Tags: neural-network, word2vec

I've been reading about neural networks and how CBOW and Skip-Gram works but I can't figure out one thing: How do I generate the word vectors itself?

It always seems to me that I use those methods to calculate the weight matrix, and I use the word vector to do adjust it, and I'm struggling to understand how I got the word vectors in the first place.

When I found Rumelhart paper I thought I would find the answer there, but all I got was the same thing: calculate the error comparing the output expected with the one I found and adjust the model. But who is my expected output? How did I get it?

For example, Omer Levy and Yoav Goldberg explained in a perfect clear way (in Linguistic Regularities in Sparse and Explicit Word Representations) how the Explicit Vector Space Representation works, but I couldn't find an explanation on how Distributed representations for words works.

Comment: You will get better response for this on Cross Validated

Comment: Have you gone through original word2vec paper? - http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf